# Disable autocommit in Apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

Is there a possibility of disabling autocommit in Apache superset for SQLLAB.
Also is there rollback feature integration possible?
As there seems to be no documentation regarding the commit and rollback feature provided by Apache superset .